# algorithm for concatenating a list of movies to a new list of concatenated movies of length no greater than a given number

Tags: algorithm

I have a (play)list **(A)** of movie clips (*a1,...,an*) with different lengths. I want to create a new list **(B)** where clips (*b1,...,bm*) are concatenated from the clips in **(A)**.

There is also a limit **MAX_LEN** that no *bx* in **(B)** may exceed. Only adjacent clips in a may be concatenated (*a1+a2+a3* is a legal concatenation, *a1+a3* is not). All clips in **(A)** must appear once in **(B)** and have to do so in the order they appeared in **(A)**

An optimal solution primary:

**1)** minimizes the number of clips in **(B)**.

and secondary:

**2)** maximizes the duration of the shortest clip in **(B)**.

The primary constraint **1)** is more inportant than **2)** so for 2 different solutions **S1** and **S2** where NumOfClips(**S1**) < NumOfClips(**S1**) then **S1** is "more optimal" than **S2** even if durationOfShortestClip(**S1**) < durationOfShortestClip(**S2**).

Here is an example that shows a input list **(A)** three possible outputs **(B1)** and **(B2)** and **(B3)**. Nether of **(B1)** or **(B2)** fulfill **1)** (although **(B2)** is better solution than **(B1)** since 25>23) The optimal solution is **(B3)**. 
[image: example of input and output lists]

I would like to know how to find an optimal solution in an efficient way? 
Other help full information/clues such as the existence or non existence of optimal sub problems, etc are also appreciated.

Comment: Does the order need to be preserved across multiple `bx`s? e.g, can we have b1 = a1+a3 and b2=a2+a4. Can clips `ax` be repeated in B? Does B need to contain all clips from A?

Comment: Good questions, I updated my question to cover them.

Comment: According to what all inputs you will sort items from listA ?

Comment: Sahal and Faruk Sahin I don't understand your questions.

Comment: For 2 different solutions A,B : If `NumOfClips(A) < NumOfClips(B)` and `durationOfShortestClip(A) < durationOfShortestClip(B)`. Which one is more optimal, A or B?

Comment: In your example, isn't `[ab, cde, fg]` the optimal solution? The number of clips is minimized (3), the durations are all less than `MAX_LEN` (35, 59, 50 respectively), and the duration of the shortest clip is maximized (35).

Comment: I should also mention that this feels like a combinatorial optimization problem along the lines of bin packing, subset sum, and the knapsack problem. These are at least NP-hard, but if your data set is small enough, reasonably fast algorithms exist. Otherwise, approximation algorithms should work. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem for more info.

Comment: As you have set the optimizaton function,the second list consists of b=**all** "a" clips concatenated together. The fact, that the clip b is long, doesn't matter because it is the secondary fact. As in word ordering - all a-words precede all b-words, and the second letter simply doesn't matter. Obviously, you want something different. So, you have to write down the function that has to be optimized.

Comment: Chris Schmich. Thanks for the Knapsack_problem insight i will look into it. And you are right about the solution; I added it now.

Comment: Gangnus. This only works in the case where the sum of all lengths in (A) is less than MAX_LEN.

Answer (score 0):

for realized The primary constraint you can used greedy algorithm.because you should set first element clips in (A) to first element in (B),now if you have empty space in first element(B),and second element clips in (A) can set in first element is (B),so do this one,else set into second element in B.
repeat this solution to set all clips in (A) appear once in (B).
in this result you have a minimizes the number of clips in (B) by o(n).
for optimal solution you realized the secondary constraint you should maximizes the duration of the shortest.
assume greedy algorithm provide B,that B(i) is i st element item in the list.it is clearly that no clip in B(i) can not appear in B(i-1),so just last members in b(i) can appears in b(i+1).
so check that move is maximizes the duration of the shortest clip in (B) or not.

Answer (score 0):

One very vague idea, but it at least proves your problem is polynomial. My solution is of the kind `O(N^3 * log N * log L)`, where L is the sum of the lengths of all clips.

First of all find the appropriate minimum possible number of clip groups `G` - this is fairly simple. Just greadily position as many as possible clips in the first group and continue on with the next one. This will for sure produce the minimal value of `G` (that is criteria 1). However, optimality according to criteria 2) is still to be found.

Here is how it goes:

- create matrix `mat[i][j]` having `mat[i][j] = 1` iff the clips with indices between `i` and `j` have sum less than `MAX_LEN`. All other values in `mat` are 0.
- You do a binary search of what is the minimal of the clips sums in all the groups. This step gives the factor of `log L` in my algorithm. Assume that at a given step the chosen value is `M`
- make copy of `mat` as `copy_mat`. `copy_mat[i][j] = 1 <=> mat[i][j] = 1 and SUM(clips i..j) >= M`
- raise this matrix to the power of the found number of clip groups `G`. The matrix multiplication gives factor of `N^3` if implemented the easiest way. Raising to power adds additional `log N` factor.
- if `copy_mat[1][N] = 1` then there is a solution with `M`, try to increase it. Otherwise - decrease.
- Decrease binary search step.

When the binary search finishes it will find the optimal value of `M`. If you need to find the exact grouping you will need to use one auxiliary matrix while doing the matrix multiplications, but I think you should be able to figure out this last bit by yourself.

I will keep on thinking of faster solution, but mine at least proves your problem is not exponential in complexity and will work with number of clips around 1000 relatively fast.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. It looks promising and I have some questions. First I don't understand what the raising the mat_copy to the power of G (number of groups) does and I will in order to figure out the grouping so place elaborate. Also using my example where optimal M=35 I get copy_mat[1][N] = 0 for bot M=35 and M=36 when using the power G=3 but G=4 gives 1 for G=35 and 0 for G=36. Is it suppose to be the power of G+1 or is this just a coincidence?

Comment: @user1622094: For the first part about raising to power. I construct a new graph having as edges all the possible combinations of clips that might fit together in a group. Then when I raise to power of G I check whether there is path of length exactly `G` connecting nodes 1 and `N`. Proof of that you can see in this post of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346103/graph-traversal-of-n-steps/10346172#10346172. Path of length exactly `G` is exactly the kind of splitting you are searching for - all clips separated in `G` groups of consecutive clips.

Comment: @user1622094: I don't get your second point: how can `G` be 35 as you do not have that many groups?